# psycopg2.InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry

Tags: python, postgresql, gis, postgis, psycopg2

```
        x = float(stand[1].split(' ')[0])
        y = float(stand[1].split(' ')[1])
        coordinate = ppygis.Point(x, y)
        coordinate.srid = SRID_WGS84
        # Stand delimiters
        delimiter = []
        line = []

        for i in range(2, len(stand)):
            # The cycle will run through everythin in the stand list
            # But it will only actually do something when it finds a coordinate
            # counter
            if (len(stand[i].split(' ')) == 1):
                # Number of coordinates to process. Adjusted for indexation
                ncoords = int(stand[i]) + 1

                for c in range(i + 1, i + ncoords, 1):
                    x = float(stand[c].split(' ')[0])
                    y = float(stand[c].split(' ')[1])

                    point = ppygis.Point(x, y)
                    point.srid = SRID_WGS84
                    line.append(point)
                line = ppygis.LineString((line))
                delimiter.append(line)
                line = []
        delimiter = ppygis.MultiLineString((delimiter))
        cur.execute("""
                INSERT INTO taxi_stands(id, name, coordinates, delimiter_geom)
                VALUES(%s, %s, ST_PointFromText(%s), %s);
                """, (taxi_stands_list.index(stand), stand_name, coordinate,
                    delimiter))
```

We are trying to insert a MultiLineString into a PostgreSQL database using Python. We are using `ppygis` to convert our coordinates to actual geometries. The stands are coordinates to be inserted. The list's format is as follows:

```
[nº of points in line, x1line1, y1line1, ..., nº of points in line, ...]
```

When inserting into the database we get this error:

```
psycopg2.InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "0101000020e6100000645d" <-- parse error at position 22 within geometry
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_pointfromtext" statement 1
```

if we change ST_PointFromText to ST_GeomFromText the error is:

```
psycopg2.InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "0101000020e6100000645d" <-- parse error at position 22 within geometry
```

The ppygis python module is also severely lacking in documentation and we don't know which is the error.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [St_PointFromText()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointFromText.html) because your geometries are already in [WKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) format (ST_PointFromText requires geometries in [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format).

Simply Change your statement so:

```
cur.execute("""
                INSERT INTO taxi_stands(id, name, coordinates, delimiter_geom)
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s);
                """, (taxi_stands_list.index(stand), stand_name, coordinate,
                    delimiter))
```